# React Animation Component Wont Update

Tags: reactjs, anime.js

I'm using the React wrapper for the anime.js animation library and am in the middle of attempting to make a application that takes user input then animates a div based on the input

(Picture for visualization)

[image]

It starts out with a basic moving square but after hitting the Animate button it would update to whatever the user had entered.

However when I hit the animate button the div just disappears entirely and if I hit it a second time the entire component parent and all disappear! It leaves me with this error message however in the console.

I've done testing and the props are getting passed to the outputDivProps object in AnimationOutput.jsx and they are correct but the div just wont update properly.

[image]

### Parent Component (Animation.jsx)

-Holds AnimationForm.jsx & AnimationOutput.jsx Components

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Segment} from 'semantic-ui-react';

import AnimationForm from './AnimationForm.jsx';
import AnimationOutput from './AnimationOutput.jsx';
import BoxChanger from './BoxChanger.jsx';

export default class Animation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        boxColor: 'white',
        boxShape: 'square',
        boxDiration: 3,
        boxTranslate: '50vw',
        boxEasing: 'linear',
        boxDelay: 0
    };
  }

  updateAni = (boxColor, boxShape, boxDiration, boxTranslate, boxEasing, boxDelay) => {
    console.log('updateAni: ' + boxColor, boxShape, boxDiration, boxTranslate, boxEasing, boxDelay);

    this.setState({
      boxColor: boxColor,
      boxShape: boxShape,
      boxDiration: boxDiration,
      boxTranslate: boxTranslate,
      boxEasing: boxEasing,
      boxDelay: boxDelay
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {boxColor, boxShape, boxDiration, boxTranslate, boxEasing, boxDelay} = this.state;

    return (<Segment inverted>
      <h2>Animation Creator!</h2>

      <AnimationForm aniUpdate={this.updateAni}/>
      <h3>Box Animations!</h3>
      <AnimationOutput boxColor={boxColor} boxShape={boxShape} boxDiration={boxDiration * 1000} boxTranslate={boxTranslate} boxEasing={boxEasing} boxDelay={boxDelay * 1000}/>
      <BoxChanger/>
    </Segment>
  );
  }
}
```

### Form Component (AnimationForm.jsx)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Form, Input, Button, Select, Radio} from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class AnimationForm extends Component {
  state = {
    boxColorValue: '',
    boxShapeValue: '',
    boxDirationValue: '',
    boxTranslateValue: '',
    boxEasingValue: '',
    boxDelayValue: ''
  };

  handleChange = (e, {name, value}) => this.setState({[name]: value});

  handleSubmit = () => {
    const {boxColorValue, boxShapeValue, boxDirationValue, boxTranslateValue, boxEasingValue, boxDelayValue} = this.state;
    this.props.aniUpdate(boxColorValue, boxShapeValue, boxDirationValue, boxTranslateValue, boxEasingValue, boxDelayValue);
  }

  render() {

    const {boxColorValue, boxDirationValue, boxTranslateValue, boxDelayValue} = this.state;

    const options = [/* Options for dropdown */]

    return (<Form inverted className='box-animation-form' size={'big'}>
      <Form.Group widths='equal'>
        <Form.Field control={Input} name='boxColorValue' value={boxColorValue} label='Color' placeholder='exp. #ffffff or white' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <Form.Field control={Input} name='boxDirationValue' value={boxDirationValue} label='Diration' placeholder='exp. 2 or 5 (seconds)' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <Form.Field control={Select} name='boxEasingValue' label='Transition Type' value={options.value} options={options} placeholder='Types' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group inline>
        <label>Shape</label>
        <Form.Field control={Radio} label='Square' checked={this.state.boxShapeValue === 'square'} onClick={() => this.setState({boxShapeValue: 'square'})}/>
        <Form.Field control={Radio} label='Circle' checked={this.state.boxShapeValue === 'circle'} onClick={() => this.setState({boxShapeValue: 'circle'})}/>
        <Form.Field control={Radio} label='Triangle' checked={this.state.boxShapeValue === 'triangle'} onClick={() => this.setState({boxShapeValue: 'triangle'})}/>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group widths='equal'>
        <Form.Field control={Input} name='boxTranslateValue' value={boxTranslateValue} label='Want it to move?' placeholder='exp. 200 or 200px' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <Form.Field control={Input} name='boxDelayValue' value={boxDelayValue} label='Delay' placeholder='exp. 1 or 2 (seconds)' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </Form.Group>
      <Button inverted color='green' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Animate!</Button>
    </Form>);
  }
}
```

### Animation Box Component (AnimationOutput.jsx)

-I think the problem is here!

```
import React from 'react';
import Anime from 'react-anime';

const AnimationOutput = (props) => {
console.log('AnimationOutput: ' + props.boxColor, props.boxShape, props.boxDiration, props.boxTranslate, props.boxEasing, props.boxDelay);

  let outputDivProps = {
    easing: 'linear',
    loop: true,
    direction: 'alternate',
    duration: props.boxDiration,
    translateX: props.boxTranslate
  };

  let outputDivStyle = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: props.boxColor
  };

console.log(outputDivProps)

  return (<div className='animation-output-box'>
    <Anime {...outputDivProps}>
      <div style={outputDivStyle}></div>
    </Anime>
  </div>);
}

export default AnimationOutput;
```

Comment: Probably a minor, but could you turn this ```<div style={outputDivStyle}></div>``` in ```AnimationOutput.jsx``` to a self-closing tag, like this: ```<div style={outputDivStyle} />```

Comment: What do you mean by 'minor'? Also I was planning on puttin text on the inside in the future. Do you think it has something with how react renders things? Or do you think its related to the animation library I'm just kinda lost now

Comment: Minor as in I'm unsure if the update will fix the problem. React (jsx) requires empty tags to be self-closing, eg, ```<div></div>``` should be written as ```<div />```

Comment: Oh I tried it but it didn't work :/ I've decided to shelve the problem and return to it tomorrow since I have other little projects to attend to.